# Ubuntu Software super slow when downloading something

Tags: software-installation

Ubuntu Software is super slow now for some reason.
I use the OS Ubuntu 20.04.3 Focal Fossa.
Please help if you can, This is stopping me from doing work.
Thanks.

I have been using it for more than an year now and there was no problem until now. When I click to install something, it straight goes to 14% then it falls back down to 0% after 3 seconds.

Before this problem, it could install a 300MB program in like 25 seconds. Also after it drops 0% it takes 4 or 5 seconds to go to 1% then 2% so on.

Here is the output of `snap list`

```
Name                    Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher     Notes
bare                    1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓    base
core18                  20211028                    2253   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
core20                  20211129                    1270   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
gimp                    2.10.28                     380    latest/stable    snapcrafters  -
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804         0+git.3556cb3               77     latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
gnome-3-38-2004         0+git.cd626d1               87     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-59-g7bca6ae             1519   latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snap-store              3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7          558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snapd                   2.53.2                      14066  latest/stable    canonical✓    snapd
wine-platform-3-stable  3.0.4                       14     latest/stable    mmtrt         -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        274    latest/stable    mmtrt         -
```

### Edit

You can fix it by:

**Restarting the Ubuntu Software centre.**

**Then restarting your PC.**

That fixed my problem.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: You should try using `snap` before throwing out problems to the software center, try `sudo snap <app name>` and post the output, does it also take that much time ?

Comment: You may post the output of `snap list` too

Comment: @Someone It works after restarting Ubuntu Software. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by:

**Restarting the Ubuntu Software centre.**

**Then restarting your PC.**

That fixed my problem.